# Does spark broadcast hash join could perform A right join B if B is the broadcasted dataset?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I read some posts saying Broadcast Hash Join could perform inner/left/right join except full join.

Let's say I have dataset A and B. B could be broadcasted to every executor and a hash table is built for it.

I could perform `A left join B` with no doubt by looping over A and matching B using the hash table.
But I wonder how right join is supported. Looping over B and matching A means the hash table is not being used.

Moreover, if right join is supported somehow, it looks like full join should be supported as well, doesn't it?

Appreciate any analysis, thanks!!!

Comment: answer not clear?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although I am not quite clear what your point is, *as you get different results* as shown per below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast
val A = Seq((3, "A", 5), (1, "A", 2), (3, "A", 5), (3, "B", 13)).toDF("key", "Categ1", "value")  
val B = Seq((3, "A", 55)).toDF("key", "Categ1", "value") 
A.join(broadcast(B), Seq("key"), "left").show()
```

returns:

```
+---+------+-----+------+-----+
|key|Categ1|value|Categ1|value|
+---+------+-----+------+-----+
|  3|     A|    5|     A|   55|
|  1|     A|    2|  null| null|
|  3|     A|    5|     A|   55|
|  3|     B|   13|     A|   55|
+---+------+-----+------+-----+
```

And this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast
val A = Seq((3, "A", 5), (1, "A", 2), (3, "A", 5), (3, "B", 13)).toDF("key", "Categ1", "value")  
val B = Seq((3, "A", 55)).toDF("key", "Categ1", "value") 
A.join(broadcast(B), Seq("key"), "right").show()
```

returns:

```
+---+------+-----+------+-----+
|key|Categ1|value|Categ1|value|
+---+------+-----+------+-----+
|  3|     B|   13|     A|   55|
|  3|     A|    5|     A|   55|
|  3|     A|    5|     A|   55|
+---+------+-----+------+-----+
```

I think your question is how right and broadcast work together. If so, then it works technically but different results are gotten.